# Registering C# app as shell app

Tags: c#, wpf, shell

I need to register my WPF application as a shell app in order to restrict some functionalities in my standard WPF C# application.

Some examples of functinalities to be restricted: Keystrokes (Alt +F4, Ctrl+Alt+Del etc.), Mouse (Right click etc.)

How can this be done?

Comment: Hard to guess what "shell app" means.  I suspect you want to google "wpf kiosk application".  The top SO hits look good.

Comment: @HansPassant: I read somewhere that to do such an app, one could replace the default shell program of Windows to the desired program, through registry settings. Is that a manual process to be done on the machine on which this app will run or is this something that could be added to the code itself? In any of the above case, it would be good to have some more details to go ahead with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't restrict Ctrl+Alt+Del with a shell app, but you can do that by changing policy settings.

You can do this in C# by using WMI. Take a look at [WMI Code Creator](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=8572).

As for Alt+F4 and Mouse events, if they are only within your application, again you don't need shell extensions. You can just handle your main window OnClose event and return Cancel.